# Detect number of edges extracted using Canny Edge Detection

Tags: python, count, detection

I want to be able to count the edges in an image which has been modified using Canny Edge Detection.

I'm currently using edge detection for a fingerprint and want to be able to determine the quality of the fingerprint by counting how many edges the edge detection has been able to extract.

Here is my current code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("../../Images/EnhancedSharpness.jpg", 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)

titles = ['Starting Image', 'Edge Detection']
images = [img, edges]
for i in range(2) :
    plt.subplot(1, 2, i+1), plt.imshow(images[i], 'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: just interested to see if you got a solution for this? I am trying to do something similar